# PHP Curl POST request not working but works fine in POSTMAN

Tags: php, json, api, curl, postman

Sending invoice details to main system from sub pos system. no errors either response in web browser. Request sent from https://example.com. But same code works fine in postman. Postman gives success response.

[works fine in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/app1w.png)

code in php

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'urlhere',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
    "key":"asdasdsad", 
    "shopId":99999, 
    "SHOP_ID": "DUF SHOP", 
    "SHOP_NAME": "DUFF SUB", 
    "INVOICE_NUMBER": "26/111", 
    "TRANSACTION_DATE": "2020-08-25 7:31:20", 
    "TRANSACTION_TIME": "7:31:20",
    "TOTAL_AMOUNT_BEFORE_DISCOUNT": 150.00, 
    "DISCOUNT_AMOUNT": 50.00, 
    "DISCOUNT_TYPE": "NO",
    "TOTAL_AMOUNT_AFTER_DISCOUNT": 100.00, 
    "productDetails":[
        { 
        "INVOICE_NUMBER":"5210/D",
        "PRODUCT_NAME": "PRODUCT", 
        "PRODUCT_CATEGORY": "cat", 
        "PRODUCT_SUB_CATEGORY": "subCat",
        "BRAND_NAME": "Brand", 
        "QUANTITY":100, 
        "UNIT_PRICE": 250.00
        }],
    "currencyDetail":[
        {
        "INVOICE_NUMBER":"1",
        "PAYMENT_METHOD": "CASH",
        "CURRENCY": "USD", 
        "ACTUAL_PAYMENT_CURRENCY_TYPE":"USD",
        "amount":250.00       
        }
        ]
   }
   ',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: text/plain'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
?>
```

Comment: A little tip: Postman has the option to generate the PHP code for you. On the right, look for an option called "Code" or denoted with a `</>` symbol, then choose `PHP - cURL`. Then you can compare the differences.

Comment: When you face issues like this, start by [debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757071/php-debugging-curl) your cURL request to see what the server actually says. Without knowing what the server responds with, you're basically just guessing, which is quite sub optimal.

Comment: @El_Vanja no difference . I checked

Comment: Shouldn't `'Content-Type: text/plain'` be `'Content-Type: application/json'` since you're sending json?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson It must be Content-Type: text/plain and now I am getting error Failed to connect to 'domainofmainsystem' port 8005: Connection refused

Comment: So your server can't connect to the remote server. Unfortunately, we have no clue what systems you're running or how things are set up so you need to do some debugging to find out why it can't connect. There can by too many reasons for this.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson it is pos system and sending invoice details to main system. Can you explain me how to debug code please?

Comment: This isn't necessary the code that's the problem. It could be some server/network configuration. As mentioned, it could be any reason and since we don't know anything about your system or network, it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: solved. It is all beacause of browser's security.

Answer (score 0):

I use this site https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/ sometimes.
otherwise you can switch to json maybe. this example works for me.

```
    $handle = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"text\": \"$newText\" , \"model_id\":\"en-fr\"}");
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'apikey' . ':' . $_ENV['API_KEY_TRANSLATE']);

    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $response = curl_exec($handle);
    $responseDecoded = json_decode($response, true);
    $responseCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);      
    curl_close($handle);
```